# applying reverse-i-search to a file

Tags: bash, command-history

The bash reverse-i-search (ctrl-R) is quite handy to find a command you typed a while ago. However, it only searches the history of the current terminal (which consists AFAIK of the history loaded at creation time of the terminal plus whatever you typed in the terminal). I would like to have the same functionality, but the search should look in a file instead.

I use multiple terminals for different tasks, so it is not desirable to mix their histories. Instead, I have them all write to a file ~/.persistent_history where all commands I type end up. I would like to have reverse-i-search do what it does, but instead of using the history of the terminal it should use the persistent history. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe setting HISTFILE with the file you want to search. I do the same -save all commands to a file- but I search it with grep.

Comment: Maybe this approach could help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32372/488150. Even if it's not the best solution.